# How to configure tomcat to rollover catalina.log log files

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat6

I'm trying to configure my tomcat to rollover log files once a size limit is reached. I'm running tomcat as a windows service and am redirecting all my stdout to catalina.log. This is how I configured by logging.properties to set a size limit. But it is not working.

logging.properties

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = e:/apache-tomcat/logs/server_111-1001
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.limit = 100000 # size 100kb 
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.count = 5


2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = e:/apache-tomcat/logs/server_111-1001
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = e:/apache-tomcat/logs/server_111-1001
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = e:/apache-tomcat/logs/server_111-1001
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

# For example, set the com.xyz.foo logger to only log SEVERE
# messages:
#org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.level=FINE
```

But 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.limit = 100000 doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Never used tomcat on windows, but I think this is just stdout/stderr and they aren't redirected in the logging.properties. You can check that if you change the file location in logging.properties. See `http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html` In my view you need a windows solution for logrotation like `http://www.sprint.net.au/~terbut/usefulbox/apachelogrot.htm` or fiddle with the tomcat service to redirect it to eventlog.

Comment: I'm actually redirecting the stdout/stderr messages to catalina.log with giveing swallowoutput=true in context element of server.xml.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the FileHandler, documented here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/FileHandler.html 
It does not have a "limit" property, it only rotates at day changes.

You can configure tomcat to use log4j which is more flexible, see this page: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j

swallowOutput in context is not recommended for use (that's what the above page says)